# lapply function with 2 count variables

Tags: r, nested, lapply, sapply

I am very green in R, so there is probably a very easy solution to this:

I want to calculate the average correlation between the column vectors in a square matrix:

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
aux<-matrix(seq(1,10000))
loop<-sapply(aux,function(i,j) cov(x[,i],x[,j])
cor_x<-mean(loop)
```

When evaluating the sapply line I get the error 'subscript out of bounds'. I know I can do this via a script but is there any way to achieve this in one line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `aux`. The variable `aux`has to range from `1` to `100` since you have `100` columns. But your `aux` is a sequence along the *rows* of `x` and hence ranges from `1` to `10000`. It will work with the following code:

```
aux <- seq(1, 100)
loop <- sapply(aux, function(i, j) cov(x[, i], x[, j]))
```

Afterwards, you can calculate mean covariance with:

```
cor_x <- mean(loop)
```

If you want to exclude duplicate fields (e.g., cov(X,Y) is inherently identical to cov(Y,X)), you can use:

```
cor_x <- mean(loop[upper.tri(loop, diag = TRUE)])
```

If you also want to exclude cov(X,X), i.e., variance, you can use:

```
cor_x <- mean(loop[upper.tri(loop)])
```

Answer (score 6):

No need for any loops. Just use `mean(cov(x))`, which does this very efficiently.

Comment: +1, I was just formulating same answer, though he does want the mean covariance

Comment: @BrodieG Well, they know how to use `mean`.

Comment: But do you need to remove the self covariance?  I guess that's relatively trivial too with `diag`, but was trying to figure out what the correct answer is though it looks like the OP is including it.

Comment: @BrodieG Well, they don't ask for that, but it's easy to use `diag` or `upper.tri` as Sven demonstrates.

Comment: Your solution is the most elegant but I picked Sven's because it explains in detail what is wrong with my loop.